# How can i add the camera and camera roll to my IOS app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

I am trying to make an app when when I press a button the camera will come up and i can have like dotted lines of were i need to have everyone put there eyes.  Or if they already have a photo the can choose it. I would like to have the buttons on one view and then when they take a picture it will be the background of the other view

I am doing this for a iphone app.

Comment: [Google?](https://www.google.com/search?q=ios+uiimagepickercontroller+camera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to look into [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html), and you can add "dotted lines" using the pickers `overlay` property.

Additionally, here's a link to a pretty good tutorial on how to accomplish this.
http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/28/getting-images-from-the-iphone-photo-library-or-camera-using-uiimagepickercontroller/

Comment: this will work with ios 5 right?

Comment: @KyleGreenlaw Of course, it is supported from iOS 2 and up